# JSPDF .output Image + txt

Tags: javascript, jspdf

So i have a jspdf script im working with.
.save works as expected and outputs the image + text elements.

How ever

**doc.output() = only text**

**doc.output('datauristring') = corrupted pdf**

I think im missing something
here is an example of my code

```js
var imgData = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQIAdgB2AAD/examplestringonly...';
var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt');
doc.text(35, 340, "data notes");
doc.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 350, 40, 200, 40);
doc.output('datauristring');
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved hope this helps anyone.

.output() was correctly sending all the date, how ever the base64 was being corrupted. so i made the php handle the datauri, and used base64_decode() on it.
then made it save to file.

fixes the issues completely.

```js
var pdf = doc.output('datauri');

        var data = new FormData();
        data.append("data" , pdf);
        data.append("id" , id);



        $.ajax({
           url: 'upload.php',
           data: data, 
           dataType: 'text',
           processData: false,
           contentType: false,
           type: 'POST',
           success: function (response) {
             console.log('Exit to send request');
           },
           error: function (jqXHR) {
             console.log('Failure to send request');
           }
        });
```

```html
<?php

if(!empty($_POST['data'])){

    $data = str_replace(' ','+',$_POST['data']);
    $data =  substr($imgData,strpos($imgData,",")+1);
    $data = base64_decode($imgData);
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $fname = "test.pdf"; // name the file
    $file = fopen("api/warranty/pdf/" .$id, 'w'); // open the file path
    fwrite($file, $data); //save data
    fclose($file);
} else {
    echo "No Data Sent";
}
```